# Qt pro файл. Не подключает статическую либу

Tags: qt, qtcreator, qmake

Пытаюсь в одной субдиректори подключить библиотеку из другой

```
QAMQP_LIBRARY_TYPE = staticlib
DEPTH = ../qamqp/src
include($${DEPTH}/../qamqp.pri)
INCLUDEPATH += $${QAMQP_INCLUDEPATH}
message ("Added QAMQP " $${INCLUDEPATH} )
LIBS += -L$${AMQP_LIBDIR}/../qamqp/src $${QAMQP_LIBS}
macx:CONFIG -= app_bundle
message("AMQP_LIBDIR = " $${AMQP_LIBDIR})
message("Libs = " $$LIBS)
"build-%{CurrentProject:Name}-%{CurrentKit:FileSystemName}-%{CurrentBuild:Name}")}
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../qamqp/src
```

Странное то, что в меседжах переменные отражены правильные. Статическая библиотека в директории присутсвует, но почему-то не линкуется - при компиляции выдает ошибки линковки.

Comment: Покажите, что содержится в `$${QAMQP_LIBS}`

Comment: Там все норм вроде  -lqamqpd

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто оказалось. В другой поддиректории в тесткейсе был один неопределенный метод. Вот он-то вообще все за собой потянул. Хотя не ясно, каким вообще образом он связана со статической либой - там даже импорт не предусмотрен.